# Mysql query: decrease value by 1

Tags: mysql

I would like decrease by 1 the value contained inside a field (integer or drop-down). I tried these 3 queries but none of them work as expected:

```
UPDATE `my_table` SET `my_field` = 'my_field-1' WHERE `other` = '123'

UPDATE `my_table` SET `my_field` = 'my_field' -1 WHERE `other` = '123'

UPDATE `my_table` SET `my_field` = '-1' WHERE `other` = '123'
```

I searched here and on Google but all solutions I found are similar. Any idea why this doesn't work at my side?

Comment: If you didn't put back ticks around all your column names you might have got it right on that second attempt

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You don't need any quotes.

```
UPDATE my_table SET my_field = my_field - 1 WHERE `other` = '123'
```

To understand, it's like a classic affectation in any languages: "I want `my_field` being equal to `my_field` (the current value) minus `1`.
If you put quotes, it means "I want `my_field` being equal to the string:

1. `'my_field-1'` (for your first query)
2. `'my_field' - 1` (which means nothing, at least for me: what the result of a string minus an integer?)
3. `'-1'`, which will be converted to -1 if your field has the INTEGER signed type.

In some cases (if you have spaces or special characters if your field name), you can surrounded the field name with `backticks`:

```
UPDATE my_table SET `my_field` = `my_field` - 1 WHERE  other = '123'
```

Answer (score 7):

Try this one remove single quotes from the column name other it will be treated as string 'my_field-1' or use back-ticks around column name

```
UPDATE my_table SET my_field = my_field - 1 WHERE `other` = '123'
```

or

```
UPDATE my_table SET `my_field` = `my_field` - 1 WHERE  `other` = '123'
```